# Java: How to make a piece of code run continuously

Tags: java

I have a piece of Java code that lasts for 5 minutes
and is scheduled to run the task every 60 seconds.

Question: How do I change the code to make it run forever and and execute the task every 1 minute:

Code:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Timer task started at:" + new Date());
    completeTask();
    System.out.println("Timer task finished at:" + new Date());
}

private void completeTask() {
    //Task to be exeucted
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    // running timer task as daemon thread
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    // schedule the task to run every 1 minute
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println("TimerTask started");
    // cancel after sometime

    try {
        Thread.sleep(300*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //timer.cancel();
    System.out.println("TimerTask cancelled");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } 

    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
 }
```

Please advise

Comment: Why are you running it as a daemon?

Comment: This timer is not getting cancelled already

Comment: I was following an example from this link:
http://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-and-timertask-example-tutorial

even if I comment the line timer.cancel()
it does not run the code forever

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, because you are running it as a daemon, the main thread will sleep for five minutes and after that no other "local" thread is running on your application and therefor the application is terminated.

If there is not a good reason for you to run the Timer as a daemon, you shouldn't.

Taken from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#Timer(boolean)) of the Timer class "A daemon thread is called for if the timer will be used to schedule repeating "maintenance activities", which must be performed as long as the application is running, *but should not prolong the lifetime of the application.*".

The simplest way to deal with this is to use the constructor without the boolean (i.e

> Timer timer = new Timer();

). This will make it run "forever".

If you, however for some reason, have to run it as a daemon, you can simply insert a while loop running forever:

> while(!false){ }

This should be put in the end of the main method.

You should keep in mind that this will also prevent the application from stopping because this code will be blocking the main thread as long as true is not equal to false (i.e forever).